# Updating an iOS app with CoreData removes all records

Tags: ios, core-data

I have updated an iOS app that has a Core Data database via the the App Store, and all my stored data got deleted.
is there a way to prevent this issue in the Xcode code?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you make changes to the Core Data model in the new version? Did you change the URL of where the Core Data store lives in your app?

Comment: no, that's why I can't understand why that happened :(

Comment: the only way to figure it out then is to revert your project back to the old version using git, run on a device or simulator. then, revert back to the current version in git and run the app again, installing over top of the previous build. This will let you simulate the update process and debug the problem

Comment: ok, thanks so much, I'll check it out.

Comment: Normally you don't have to do anything to prevent the data from being removed, because that doesn't happen. Testing the upgrade process as @PatrickGoley suggests is an important part of upgrading the app.